# Is there a way to have iPhone SDK 3 and 4b at the same time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Is there a way to have iPhone SDK 3 and 4b at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely possible. You can install XCode (and the associated iPhone SDKs) to a folder other than 'Developer', leaving your current iPhone SDK installation intact. You can use 'DeveloperBeta' for example. During the installation, right after choosing which Volume to install to, click on the 'Developer' folder entry and select 'Other' to choose a different folder.

Afterward, make sure you open your desired XCode version and open your .xcodeproj files from there, because double-clicking on .xcodeproj (or other iPhone source files) will probably open the beta XCode version by default.

Comment: For the 3.0 beta, I added them both to the dock — then you can just drag files to your desired version of Xcode. I also changed the Xcode/simulator/IB icons to red with the help of Icon Composer and Graphic Converter so I could easily distinguish them.

Comment: Great idea, tc. Good way to keep them separated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just install into a different location during install. Some common parts will get updated but his hasn't been a problem so far as I know.